# Trying to understand Kafka's KStream concept

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

```
@StreamListener("notification-input-channel")
@SendTo("notification-output-channel")
public KStream<String,Notification> process(KStream<String,PosInvoice> input)
{
     KStream<String,Notification> notificationStream=input.
     filter(k,v)->v.getCustomerType.equals("Prime").
     mapValues(v->recordBuilder.getNotification(v);

    return notificationStream;
}
```

Firstly I am totally new to Kafka. Now comming to my question is in the input KStream I am getting the value as String and Kafka then converting it into PosInvoice object. but in the notificationStream what is the purpose of the String as key? And what is the purpose of returning a KStream object? As per my knowledge KStreams are required when I have to simulatenously Read from a the topic and Write into the topic. Can you please explain the code's data flow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're never modifying the keys, so doesn't really matter what their values are. They are used to partition the output to the `@SendTo` topic. You have also defined a key `StringSerde` somewhere to read from `notification-input-channel` topic.

The purpose of returning a KStream is because this is what the method signature expects and Spring's Lifecycle hooks will build into a Kafka Streams Topology.

Comment: Yes I saw "defined a key StringSerde" in the yml file. Then how the byte array is getting converted to PosInvoice or Notification object? No custom Serde is defined in this regard....

Comment: You have to define the value serde somewhere, as well. This could be JSON or Avro, for example. I don't think Spring is smart enough to detect what deserialization method to use

Comment: Okay makes sense now.